# Rearranging pandas dataframe for grouped bar charts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that roughly looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["property_1", "property_2", "value"], index=my_index)

my_index    property_1    property_2    value
<1, 1, 1>   "A"           "X"           ...
<1, 1, 1>   "A"           "Y"           ...
<1, 1, 2>   "A"           "X"           ...
<1, 1, 4>   "A"           "X"           ...
<1, 1, 4>   "A"           "Y"           ...
<1, 1, 4>   "B"           "X"           ...
<1, 1, 4>   "B"           "Y"           ...
```

I'm wanting to produce a grouped bar chart like this:

[image: desired group bar chart]

This is quite complicated, but basically:

1. I need to reduce `my_index` to the unique indices that have a value for each combination of `property_1` and `property_2`
2. I need to find the **unique** combinations of `property_1` **AND** `property_2`, not just the unique values of each column individually!
3. I am trying to group them primarily by `my_index`, and then by the combination of `property_1` and `property_2`

I would have guessed that the way of going about this is by having a dataframe with the following layout:

```
my_index    A-X    A-Y    B-X    B-Y    ... 
<1, 1, 1>   ...    ...    NaN    NaN    ...
<1, 1, 2>   ...    ...    NaN    NaN    ...
```

And so on. Then one could drop the columns with any `NaN` values in it. You could then just call `df.plot.bar(...)` on that resulting dataframe.

But I am not sure how to rearrange these rows into the columns in this way. Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I should note that I don't **need** an answer in pandas, I am just asking if there is one. If not, I can wrangle the data out myself. But maybe pandas has a nifty one-liner for making this kind of work easier.

Comment: Please include a sample for your *data* object for a [MCVE]. See also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrongly understood your problem. But let me suggest some steps that might help you out.

First, add one column `unique_property` from columns `property_1` and `property_2`, and (if needed) drop the two latter.

```
df[`unique_property`] = df.property_1 + df.property_2
df.drop(['property_1', 'property_2'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Then we can plot the dataframe, grouped by `my_index` and `unique_property`.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(df['my_index'].unique()) # this sets x axis.
df.groupby(["my_index", "unique_property"]).mean()['value'].unstack().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
```

**Explanation for the last line.**

`df.groupby(["my_index", "unique_property"]).mean()['value']`

Above code will give us Series of `value`, grouped by `my_index` and `unique_property`. If we directly plot it, then we will get all combination of unique values in (`my_index`, `unique_property`) as x axis. That's why we need to

`unstack()` it.

It's like the unique values in `my_index` become rows and the unique values in `unique_property` become columns.

By default, it will produce `NaN` value for incomplete data, e.g. for `my_index = <1,1,1>` there are only `AX` and `AY` that have value, then `BX` and `BY` will be filled by `NaN` value. We can for example replace `NaN` by `some_value`, then `unstack(fill_value=some_value)`.